# Google Cloud Vision API Oct 2021 Upgrade Error - Access Previous Version

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-vision

The October2021/January2022 Vision API produces significant changes from the previous version running up to September2021.

The October2021/January 2022 version's return JSON has less information compared to the previous September2021 version.  These JSON file statistic (file size KB, # JSON lines) show the differences.   The same image PNG file was run:

```
September2021 (more data)
```

File 1  1,666 KB / 114,856 lines

File 2  675 KB / 45,687

Using Features parameter with and without: "model": "builtin/legacy"      produces the same result.

October2021/January2022  (less data)

File 1  1.435 KB / 102.275 lines

File 2  584 KB / 41,778

Release notes link:  https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes

Google Vision is a core function of my application.  The upgrade has "broken" my application.

```
# Python application calls Vision API
```

Python version: 3.8.5

```
google-api-core==1.22.4

google-api-python-client==1.12.3

google-auth==1.28.1

google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4

google-cloud-core==1.6.0

google-cloud-documentai==0.4.0

google-cloud-storage==1.37.1

google-cloud-vision==2.0.0

google-crc32c==1.1.2

google-resumable-media==1.2.0

googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
```

How can I access the previous version?

Comment: Have you tried installing the old version using `pip install google-cloud-vision==<specific_version_here>`?

Comment: Ricco.  The above installed libraries have not changed.  The JSON returned from the API call has changed due to the Google updating their Vision API model.

Comment: The updated May 2, 2022 Release Notes allows access to the previous version.  "The legacy models can still be accessed until August 02 2022. Specify "builtin/legacy" in the model field of a Feature object to get the old model results. After August 02, 2022 the legacy models will no longer be offered."   Has anyone successfully access the "builtin/legacy" version?     https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes

Comment: Google Vision Engineers: This is a critical Production issue. Please provide detailed Python sample code. Thx. –

Comment: Google Vision May 5 Release Note Update.  https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes    Python "Features" parameter code to access legacy version: { "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION", "model": "builtin/legacy" } , { "type": "TEXT_DETECTION", "model": "builtin/legacy" }